# GetEvent() returns null for attached event

Tags: wpf, events, reflection

When I try to get the eventinfo of a WPF 'rectangle', if the routedEvent is a native event to the object (e.g. 'MouseDown') it works (assignments are for example only).

```
DependencyObject d = rectangle;
string routedEvent = "MouseDown";

EventInfo eventInfo = d.GetType().GetEvent(routedEvent, 
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

But when I want to get the EventInfo for an attached event (I think I am using that term correctly) on the rectangle like:

```
string routedEvent = "Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Contacts.ContactDownEvent";
```

GetEvent() returns null

Any idea on how to get the eventinfo for an attached event.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the more specific [`EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventmanager.getroutedeventsforowner.aspx) method.

I believe the MSDN docs are incorrect when they say:

> Base classes are included in the
>   search.

Here's proof:

```
Debug.Assert(EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner(typeof(Rectangle)) == null);
Debug.Assert(EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner(typeof(Shape)) == null);
//even though FrameworkElement is a base class of the above!
Debug.Assert(EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner(typeof(FrameworkElement)) != null);
```

Therefore, you may need to crawl the type hierarchy yourself, or if it's a one-off just pass in `typeof(FrameworkElement)` instead or `typeof(Rectangle)`.

Comment: RoutedEvent[] routedEvents = EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner(d.GetType()); returns null?
I verified d.GetType() returns rectangle.

Comment: Kent, thank for the advice. I feel like I am getting closer. 
My original request was to get the EventInfo object because I want to add an event handler (via .AddEventHandler). If I get a RoutedEvent type instead of EventInfo (via your recommendation), how do I add a handler? Thanks

Comment: @Dan

I'm facing the same scenario as you. Did you find a solution to the EventInfo and RoutedEvent problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because attached events are not exposed as regular C# events. In the `Mouse` class, there is nothing like that :

```
public event MouseButtonEventHandler MouseDown;
```

Instead, there is a static field `MouseDownEvent` of type `RoutedEvent` :

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent MouseDownEvent;
```

You use the `EventManager` to subscribe/unsubscribe to the event.